# Get size correct information of NSButton

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

**Context**

I have an NSButton initialized via Interface Builder, linked via IBOutlets into the code and wanted to retrieve its size information (frame or bounds).

The size information should be used to generate an NSImage that wills out the whole NSButton.

When using `button.frame.size` in `viewDidLoad()` I am not receiving the correct size information.

**code:**

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let buttonSize = button.frame.size

        let standardImage = NSImage(gradientColors: [NSColor.black, NSColor.white], imageSize: buttonSize)
        let hoverImage = NSImage(gradientColors: [NSColor.white, NSColor.black], imageSize: buttonSize)

        if let standardImage = standardImage, let hoverImage = hoverImage {
            button.setImages(imageOriginal: standardImage, imageHover: hoverImage)
        }
    }
```

**Issue**

Using `button.frame.size` gives me 129 x 32 as the size.

However, doing a measurement with a screenshot gave me different sizes:
[image]

The image I have generated from the information above is proportional to the actual size of the button.

What did I overlook?

Comment: Please show your code where you are getting size because size changes as per the view lifecycle.

Comment: It is difficult for the community to diagnose your issue without posting related code. There are any number of reasons why this could be happening

Comment: Understood, I have just updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you will have a correct size of the button in the `viewDidLoad()` if you do not set it by yourself. Why is that?

1. `viewDidLoad()` is for loading the view, no layout is done here yet.
2. In `viewDidLoad()` the view is loaded but is not added to view hierarchy so it cannot be laid out if it depends on the container size and hence the button also cannot be laid out even if it is added to the superview.
3. In `viewDidLoad()` button size can be only determined according to its content size but:

   - I don't see that logic in your example
   - if button size depends on some constraints it's size might change after laying out

You can perform a simple test by changing the text of the centred button in `viewDidLoad()` and print the frame in different points of the lifecycle of the view controller.

```
viewDidLoad() button.frame = (200.0, 118.0, 81.0, 32.0) title: Button
viewDidLoad() button.frame = (200.0, 118.0, 81.0, 32.0) title: Long Button
viewWillAppear() button.frame = (200.0, 118.0, 81.0, 32.0) title: Long Button
updateViewConstraints() button.frame = (200.0, 118.0, 81.0, 32.0) title: Long Button
viewWillLayout() button.frame = (200.0, 118.0, 81.0, 32.0) title: Long Button
viewDidLayout() button.frame = (183.0, 118.0, 114.0, 32.0) title: Long Button
viewDidAppear() button.frame = (183.0, 118.0, 114.0, 32.0) title: Long Button
```

You can see that in `viewDidLayout()` the frame should be correct.

Comment: I understood 1. and 2. and was wondering if `viewDidLayout()` or `viewDidAppear()` would help. With regards to 3., does it mean that retrieving the parameters from constraints would be the solution to get the proportion of the button to generate an image that is filling out the button completely?

Comment: It is a good point. In `viewDidLoad()` you can sometimes read dimensions of the button from constraints if the button has fixed at least one dimension. Then if you have an outlet or can find the constraint (for example width or height constraint), you can read its `constant` and `multiplier`. You can also try to compute the value from other constraints. There are plenty of possibilities, regardless of the case.

In `viewDidAppear()`  frame will be already set. But this is also the point where the screen is already visible so if you change image here the change will be on display.